# Topic 12 10 Pyschool Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Below is an example from the exercise of regular expression.

```
re.search(regex1, 'a1b22c333d4444').groups()
```

The above expression's required result is

('22', '333')

What would be the complete expression of 
`regex1 = r"([ ]{2})[^ ]([ ]{ })"`?

Comment: This looks like HW.  Where is your attempt/code?

Comment: This site is for programming problems. This is not a problem, but an assignment. You learn nothing by asking for a solution; ask for an explanation instead. What part of the assignment is confusing to you? What specifically is preventing you from solving it for yourself? Can you explain in words what the incomplete regexp means? If not, why not?

Comment: Agreed Amanda. I take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're asking for help on HW.  So instead of writing the code for you in the format that is expected, here is another way to get to the solution, so that you can work on it yourself. `(\d{2}).+(\d{3})`.  You can practice your regular expressions here -> http://pythex.org/

Comment: I remove my reply because yours is encouraging to DIY :)

Comment: @antoni a that's very nice thing to do :-).  Hoping that the hint is taken lol.

Comment: Sure . i'll buy that and in future i'll try to solve on my own and ask for explanation rather than solution